# In how many ways can one pay 1000 cents using

Tags: combinatorics

The problem asks to determine the number of ways one can pay $1000$ cents using pieces of $10$ cents and $20$ cents.

My approach was as follows :

The sought number is but the number of couples of naturals $(x,y)$ satisfying

$$10x+20y=1000$$

or $$x + 2y = 100$$

This number is the number of way to write $100$ as the sum of an even number and another natural so it's $51$.

I read somewhere that this depends on whether the order of choice of the pieces matters or not (the latter being the case I dealt with)

Is my approach correct ? and What about the case where the order matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct; usually, when you count the number of ways to make change, only the number of coins of each type present matters, not the order they are handed to the cashier. And the number of $2$ coins can be anywhere between $0$ and $50$ inclusive, which determines the number of $1$ coins.

If order does matter, it turns out the number of ways to make change for $1000$ using $10$s and $20$s, or equivalently make change for $100$ using $1$s and $2$s, is $F_{101}$, the $101^{st}$ Fibonacci number. Letting $a_n$ be the number of ordered sequences of $1$s and $2$s adding to $n$, you can show that $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, by conditioning on whether the last coin is a $1$ or a $2$. This is the same as the Fibonacci recurrence, so a quick verification of the two base cases $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$ proves that $a_n=F_{n+1}$.

Comment: I really like the Fibonacci argument, +1.